# What is a condensate pump on a boiler heating system?

Tags: heating

I have searched all the online glossaries and dictionaries related to home systems and cannot find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is sort of like a small bilge pump mounted below the boiler that empties a small overflow  reservoir of water that is expelled during the condensation mode of a condensing/modulated boiler.  These are common on newer wall mounted high efficiency boilers.